# How to create tab and grid in admin product edit page Magento2

Tags: tabs, grid, magento2

Here I am using event observer "controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_catalog_product_edit" to render custom module grid in product tab but not working.

Here I have created Grid.php file.

Please help.

1. I have created below observer file.
   app/code/Namespace/Module/Observer/AddStockMovementsTab.php
   Trying to write code in this file.
2. app/code/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Watch/Grid.php

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Watch;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended {

protected $_registry;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
 */
protected $moduleManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory]
 */
protected $_setsFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
 */
protected $_productFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type
 */
protected $_type;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
 */
protected $_status;
protected $_collectionFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
 */
protected $_visibility;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory
 */
protected $_websiteFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory $setsFactory
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $type
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $status
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $visibility
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
 * @param array $data
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
    \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
    \Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Watch\Collection $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    $this->_websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
}

public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    $this->setId('StockWatchGrid');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setFilterVisibility(!$this->getProduct());
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setUseAjax(false);
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->load();

    if ($this->getProduct()) {
        $stockItem = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($this->getProduct()->getId());
        if ($stockItem->getId()) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('item_id', $stockItem->getId());
        }
    } else {
        $collection->joinProduct();
    }

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

/**
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    if (!$this->getProduct()) {
        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header'           => __('SKU'),
                'index'            => 'sku',
                'filter_index'     => 'product.sku',
                'type'             => 'text',
                'frame_callback'   => [$this, 'decorateSku'],
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
            ]
        );
    }

    $this->addColumn(
        'qty',
        [
            'header'        => __('Quantity'),
            'index'         => 'qty',
            'class' => 'sort_order'
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'movement',
        [
            'header' => __('Movement'),
            'index'  => 'movement',
            'class' => 'sort_order'
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'is_in_stock',
        [
            'header'  => __('In Stock'),
            'index'   => 'is_in_stock',
            'type'    => 'options',
            'options' => [
                '1' => __('Yes'),
                '0' => __('No'),
            ],
            'class' => 'sort_order'
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'message',
        [
            'header' => __('Message'),
            'index'  => 'message',
            'class' => 'sort_order'
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'user',
        [
            'header' => __('User'),
            'index'  => 'user',
            'class' => 'sort_order'
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        'created_at',
        [
            'header'       => __('Date'),
            'index'        => 'created_at',
            'type'         => 'datetime',
            'class' => 'sort_order'
        ]
    );

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->_registry->registry('product');
}

public function decorateSku($value, $row)
{
    $html = sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>',
        $this->getUrl('catalog/product/edit', array('id' => $row->getProductId())), __('Edit Product'),
        $value
    );

    return $html;
}}
```

Comment: Can you post what you've done so far to try to fix it?

Comment: You need to change your custom grid according to UI Component, because magento 2 used that.

Comment: @rrd I have just created grid for it and don't know what to write in observer file and which event need to use.

I have posted below my Grid.php file.